# mu4e change the face for my own mails in the header view

Tags: mu4e

I am fairly new with mu4e and set it up for multiple accounts in combination with mbsync on macos.

It is quite unconvenient for me to see my own email, which I sent on the header view for each maildir. I think I see the benefit and I am looking now for an option to change the face a bit to distinguish easier my own mails from the other mails.

Unfortunately I could not find a special mu4e face for it!?

And I tried out the proposal [Colouring mail headers by recipient email addr](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32633/colouring-mail-headers-by-recipient-email-addr) but this is removing all other faces and results in plain white faces for all headers.

The :from-or-to option does not help so much for this it seems.
Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: I don't think there is a special face for it, but if that bothers you, you can modify your bookmarks to exclude yourself adding something like `not from:whateveryouremailis` or anything that matchs it

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is certainly an option to handle this. Thanks!

Comment: And I figured out that I do not see these when I toggle related message with the keybinding "W"... thank you! For me, this would be solved even, if my initial question was slighly different. But I assume that I am not able to close this....

Comment: in fact this may fit your needs, but the question is how to apply a face (probably a custom face) to your own messages, so IMHO it should be kept open.

Comment: yes, thank you very much